# How to make a density plot for an isotropic function written in cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, graphics, functions, mathematical-optimization

$f(\rho,z)=2\rho^2+\frac{2}{3}z^2 \quad$   is a function in the cylindrical coordinate system $(\rho,\theta,z)$

The function $f(\rho,z)$ is isotropic because it does not depend on the angle $\theta$. Therefore, a plot of the density distribution of the function $f(\rho,z)$ can be obtained.
I would like to get a density plot of the function $f$, where the function's dependence on $z$ is shown by the density (in color).

How could this graph be plot?

Perhaps `DensityPlot` or `ContourPlot` are suitable for this type of plot.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define the function you want and use one of the following Mathematica functions. If I understand what you are asking for

```
f[\[Rho]_, z_] := 2 \[Rho]^2 + (2/3) z^2

DensityPlot[f[\[Rho], z], {\[Rho], 0, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 FrameLabel -> {"\[Rho]", "z", "Density"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

or

```
f[\[Rho]_, z_] := 2 \[Rho]^2 + (2/3) z^2

ContourPlot[f[\[Rho], z], {\[Rho], 0, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, Contours -> 20, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", ContourLabels -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\[Rho]", "z"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

***Updated***

To plot the projection of a sphere onto a plane while showing the distance from a specific point on the sphere to the plane as a density distribution (color), here's how you can do it:

- Define the parameters of the sphere and the point:

```
(* Sphere parameters *)
sphereRadius = 2;
sphereCenter = {0, 0, 3}; (* Center of the sphere *)

(* Point parameters *)
pointOnSphere = {0, 0, 5}; (* Coordinates of a point on the sphere *)
```

- Create a function that calculates the distance from the point on the sphere to the plane for a given point on the plane:

```
distanceToPlane[pointOnPlane_, pointOnSphere_] := 
  EuclideanDistance[pointOnSphere, pointOnPlane]
```

- Create a density distribution plot where the x and y axes represent the coordinates of the plane, and the color represents the distance from the point on the sphere to the plane:

```
DensityPlot[
  distanceToPlane[{x, y, 0}, pointOnSphere], 
  {x, -sphereRadius, sphereRadius}, {y, -sphereRadius, sphereRadius}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Distance from Sphere Point to Plane"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I meant something else. On the abscissa axis in your case is `[\Rho]`, on the ordinate axis is z, the density shows the distribution of the function depending on these two coordinates. I would like to get the following graph: on the abscissa axis is `[\Rho]`, on the ordinate axis is `[\Rho]`, and the density shows the distribution of the function depending on z.

Comment: I will give an example: how to plot a projection of a sphere onto a plane, in such a way that, through the distribution of density (color), show the distance from a specific point on the sphere to the plane?

Comment: @MamMam I have updated my answer, according to what I understand from your comments. I think it might be helpful